# rails custom validation failing unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations, has-one

I have a test that triggers a validation - uncommenting one line in the setup causes the validation to fail. The validation I expect is that two items should not point to the same app (or same app cannot have two items). However, in my test, there are two different apps (`@app` and `my_app`), and two different items (`@item` and `my_item`) pointing to each app (`@item.app = @app` and `my_item.app = my_app`). So, the validation should not be triggered, but it does get triggered.

```
# item_validator.rb
class ItemValidator
  def initialize(item)
    @item = item
  end

  def validate
    # the if condition below gets triggered unexpectedly - see the test below
    if(@item.app && 
        (Item.exists? {|item| ((item.app.id == @item.app.id) && (item != @item))}) 
    )
      @item.errors[:base] << "Same app cannot have two items"
    end
  end
end

# item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base      
  ... 
  belongs_to :app

  validate do |item|
    ItemValidator.new(item).validate
  end
 end

# app.rb
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :item, dependent: :destroy
end

# item_test.rb
class ItemTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @app = App.create!(name: "an_app")
    # >>> Uncommenting the next line triggers the validation in the test below
    # @item = Item.create!(name: 'some item', app: @app)
  end

test "can create item" do
    my_app = App.create! name: "my_app"
    # the next line triggers the validation when the line in setup is uncommented.
    my_item = Item.create!(name: "my item", app: my_app)
  end

  def teardown
    @admin = nil
    @item = nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you writing a custom validator and going through all this trouble instead of using [`uniqueness`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) validator?

Comment: @User089247- because I have a series of other validations that require custom validation (not shown here), which are run before this case is reached.

Comment: try to change your condition: `if @item.app && Item.count.where(app_id: @item.app_id) > 1` and see if it works

Comment: @User089247 Actually, for this case, I could probably do uniqueness, but am not sure if it works with nulls - are two nulls considered the same and a violation of uniqueness (item.app is not required to be present, shd be unique only if present).

Comment: You can do: `validates :app, uniqueness: true, allow_nil: true` in your item.rb but I am not sure if it answer your question since you're trying to figure out how to do that custom validation work you mentioned above. It will add a maintenance overhead for sure, plus headache of a proper test coverage.

Comment: @User089247 I tried the other suggestion (you meant `where(...).count` I presume), but this now causes the validation to always pass, even if I create two items with the same app_id.

Comment: The last suggestion (`validates :app, uniqueness: true, ...`) worked! I realized that I could do this independent of the other custom validations, so thanks!

Comment: Cool. Yes, I meant `where(...).count` but I don't understand why that will pass always? As an item with an app_id will be one and if an item with that app id exists then count will be 1 so `where(...).count > 1` should be false and validation should not be triggered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64074/discussion-between-anand-and-user089247).